# Nginx Forbideen 403

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

i run a streaming service via Nginx server ,

i want to run the stream ( format m3u8) via only 1 domain

```
    server {
        listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
     if ($host != "www.mydomain.com") {

            return 403;
        }
}
```

here when i test the link for example : http://ip_server_stream/live/1.playlist.m3u8 on browser it give Forbideen 403 error on all domains

if i put only

```
server {
            listen 80;
        server_name www.mydomain.com;
}
```

it works on all domains and VLC

i want only the link http://ip_server_stream/live/1.playlist.m3u8 works on www.mydomain.com not other domains or vlc

my nginx version is 1.7.5

this is my nginx confige file

this is my config file , it give error 403 on all domains even if i have an IF condition

```
worker_processes  8;
        error_log  logs/error.log debug;
        events {
        worker_connections  1024;
        }
        rtmp {
        server {
        listen 1991;
        allow play all;

        application live {
        allow play all;
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_nested on;
        hls_path /HLS/live;

        }


        }
        }


        http {
        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;


        server {
            listen 80;
        if ($http_host != "www.mydomain.com") {

                    return 403;
                }


        location /live {

        index  index.html index.htm;


        types {
        application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
        }
        alias /HLS/live;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        }



        location / {

        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        }   
        }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
if ($http_host != "www.mydomain.com") {
    return 403;
}
```

Comment: is there any way to disable user to use the link via VLC ? with cors i can disable other sites to use it but VLC or on mobile it stay works

Comment: sorry... i am not familiar with VLC. I can help about only nginx. please see another answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make two servers. One of them is dummy just return 403 response.

```
http {

    # dummy server.
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;

        location / {
            return 403;
        }
    }

    # main server.
    server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.mydomain.com;

      # PLEASE WRITE YOUR CONFIGURATION.
    }
}
```

Comment: same problem as before , can you check my code of congif if something wrong ?

Comment: Really? Please check the response status code is right such like change the return code from 403 to 503. I suspect that you failed to reload the config.